# Does .net BinaryFormatter support inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I currently have a socket application that I use to send string back and forth from a client to a server.  I recently decided that it would make more sense to send serialized objects  instead but ran into a problem.  I converted the code to use the SoapFormatter which allowed me to serialize the objects to string and send the string.  I ran into an issue on the client side when trying to deserialize inherited objects.  It seems that the soapformatter does not support inheritance.  The problem occured during deserialization, if i tried to deserialize the parent object when i send the child object (I dont know if this is correct terminology) it would throw a cast exception.

My question is, does the BinaryFormatter support inheritance??

Comment: Post Code...your question does not make a great deal of sense.

Comment: Are you doing the de/serialization yourself, or is it a part of a service call using Remoting/web-services/WCF? Maybe the problem isn't with your serializer, but with the service contract.

Comment: `Does .net BinaryFormatter support inheritance?` Good example for XY problem http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `SoapFormatter` and `BinaryFormatter` support serializing objects of types that inherit from other types. In other words, both do support inheritance.

You should probably ask another question about your specific problem with `SoapFormatter`. Also, just using different formatter most likely won't fix your problem (but you coul've tried it before asking here).

Comment: Yes, it looks like they do support inheritance.  I read somewhere else that it did not.  I found out my issue was that when each class is serialized it is marked with a signature "ExampleMessage version=1.0.0.0 project=server" or something like that.  I am using a linked file called ExampleMessage.cs which is the same for the server and the client but the serializer treats it as a different classes since it is built by different projects.  Therefore it throws a cast exception when deserializing.

Comment: Yes, the type has to be from the same assembly when serializing as when deserializing, under normal circumstances.